# How to prove "If H is a hereditary set, then ℘(H) is also a hereditary set."?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, first-order-logic, solution-verification

A set S is called a hereditary set if every x ∈ S is also a hereditary set.
If H is a set, then ℘(H) is the power set of H.

**Theorem:** If H is a hereditary set, then ℘(H) is also a hereditary set.
**Proof:** Let H be a hereditary set. We will prove that ℘(H) is also a hereditary set. To do so, let F ∈ ℘(H) and let x ∈ F. Since F ∈ ℘(H), we know that F ⊆ H. This means x ∈ H. Since H is a hereditary set, it follows that x is also a hereditary set. Therefore, F must be a hereditary set which means ℘(H) is also a hereditary set.  ∎

Question: Is my proof on the right track? Any critique on style is also welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Does ℘(H) mean somehing?

Comment: ℘(H) is the power set of H. I will make note of this in my question.